# How does CSVDE find the server?

Tags: active-directory, csvde

I have a command that works, but the command line is missing the "Server Name".  How does it know how to connect to AD data store?  Here is my command:

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\csvde -f "d:\ssis_packages\scripts\ActiveDirectory\Exchange_Export_Data.csv" -r "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))" -l "sAMAccountName, employeeNumber, Name, mail"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is part of the domain, so using the DNS it contact a Domain Controler.